# Selecting children

Tags: jquery, html-table

I have the below html stucture:

```
<td title="Test Info - Displays another Web page on this Web page. The other Web page is presented in an IFrame." class="ms-WPHeaderTd" id="WebPartTitleWPQ2">
  <h3 class="ms-standardheader ms-WPTitle" style="width: 778px; text-align: justify; overflow:  hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis;" name="MSOFixedWidthTitle" fixedWidth="800px">
     <nobr>
        <span>
         Text - I want this text           
           <span id="WebPartCaptionWPQ2"/>
```

And so I am trying to get the text value of the span under the `td` with id of: `WebPartTitleWPQ2` by doing the next:

```
var spans =  $("#WebPartTitleWPQ2").children("span")
```

SO then `spans.length` is always 0.

What am I doing wrong?

**Edit**

Doing

```
  $("#WebPartTitleWPQ2").find("span").text()
```

results in returning of two values both of which are `blank`

Comment: have you tried `$("#WebPartTitleWPQ2").find("span")`

Comment: Can you show us the HTML for the full td node? (Including any closing tags.)

Answer (score 8):

```
$('#WebPartTitleWPQ2 span').eq(1).text()
```

Comment: Note, however, that `.eq(1)` will select the second span(if one exists, else it won't select anything), while removing `.eq(1)` will give the text of all spans.

Comment: Well, but I only get blank values of the text() method with your selector, even when removing the .eq(1) part.

Comment: <span id="WebPartCaptionWPQ2"/> there's no span closing tag so it's empty. Check your markup

Comment: @chepe263 - it is SharePoint generated - I am not doing anything as far as generating the markup!!

Answer (score 6):

`$(selector).children()` only returns direct children of the selected tag.  To look for things further down, you can use either

```
$(selector).find(descendantSelector)
```

or, in your case,

```
$('#WebPartTitleWPQ2').find('span')
```

EDIT: Didn't see the second/nested span.  Either of these should work.  [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/c5SjS/)

```
$('#WebPartTitleWPQ2').find('span').eq(0).text();
```

or

```
$('#WebPartCaptionWPQ2').parent().text();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#WebPartTitleWPQ2').find('span').html();
```

That should get the HTML contained in the first span after this item.

EDIT: I just took another look at the markup you posted - does your span have an ID or is that another span nested within your first span? If not your markup is messed up.